# Windows requires a click to activate a window before a second click will select a button. How can I change this?

Tags: .net, winforms

My application is a C# Windows Forms Application and .Net somehow makes the default behavior of my main menu bar and tool strip buttons to be that you have to first click on my app's window (anywhere), before it will let you click the menu or tool strip button. How can I change this?

Old apps like Notepad and WordPad don't behave this way. But all the Microsoft Office apps do. But this is so annoying!

It gets worse because my app pops up secondary windows and each time I change windows, I have to first activate the blasted window before I can do anything. Ugh!

I am hoping there is some global way to change this behavior, so I don't have to override lots of controls individually (I haven't tried that). Does anybody know?

Note that controls on my app's dialogs don't exhibit this stupid behavior. Why are they different?

Comment: This sounds like using any program under Mac OS X.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, I ended up finding my own solution that it pretty simple. I derive my own ToolStrip class (and MenuStrip class) as follows:

```
// This version of ToolStrip enables mouse click's even when the main form is NOT active.
private class MyToolStrip : ToolStrip
{
    const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
    const uint WM_LBUTTONUP   = 0x202;

    static private bool down = false;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg==WM_LBUTTONUP && !down) {
            m.Msg=(int)WM_LBUTTONDOWN; base.WndProc(ref m);
            m.Msg=(int)WM_LBUTTONUP;
            }

        if (m.Msg==WM_LBUTTONDOWN) down=true;
        if (m.Msg==WM_LBUTTONUP)   down=false;

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

It appears that, just like the Mac OS X, Windows has made a GUI style decision that requires one to first activate a window BEFORE it will allow any controls to be selected. However, Windows only does this for specific controls, like ToolStrip and MenuStrip. When your window is NOT active, these controls are not sent the mouse DOWN event. I'm not sure how WinForms enforces this GUI guideline, but perhaps it uses a message filter using Application.AddMessageFilter().

Regardless, the MenuStrip controls STILL get the mouse UP event. And that inspired my solution. I simply look for any mouse UP event that is missing it's corresponding DOWN event. When I see this peculiar case, I generate my own mouse DOWN event, and for the ToolStrip controls, the world is all happy. :-)

Comment: i tried this and it works great. This has been bugging me for awhile too.

Comment: I too find this behaviour really annoying and inconsistent.  Is there any solution for the built-in Office controls?

Answer (score 2):

easy and clean solution

```
public class MyToolStrip : System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip
{
    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.CanFocus && !this.Focused)
            this.Focus();

        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both AZDean's **MyToolStrip solution** as well as Rahmat's **easy and clean solution** work fine in terms of triggering a menu, toolbar or status bar action at activating an application. However, both approaches have the side-effects described further below.

So here's a refined implementation of the **MyToolStrip solution**:

```
// This version of ToolStrip enables mouse click's even when the main form is NOT active.
private class MyToolStrip : ToolStrip
{
    const uint WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
    const uint WM_LBUTTONUP   = 0x202;

    static private bool enhancementIsActive = false;
    static private bool down = false;

    public static void ActivateEnhancement()
    {
        enhancementIsActive = true;
    }

    public static void DeactivateEnhancement()
    {
        enhancementIsActive = false;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (enhancementIsActive) {
            if (m.Msg==WM_LBUTTONUP && !down) {
                m.Msg=(int)WM_LBUTTONDOWN; base.WndProc(ref m);
                m.Msg=(int)WM_LBUTTONUP;
                }
            }

        if (m.Msg==WM_LBUTTONDOWN) down=true;
        if (m.Msg==WM_LBUTTONUP)   down=false;

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Calling `ActivateEnhancement()` and `DeactivateEnhancement()` is a bit tricky. The remarks in the `StripClickEnhancement` source code referred to below explain all the details, here's the summary:

1. The enhancement is to be activated by the forms `Deactivate` event, **unless the event got triggered by opening an OpenFileDialog**. This prevents the side-effect on double-clicking a file in the dialog.
2. The enhancement is to be deactivated by the forms `Activate` event, **but deactivation must be delayed by e.g. the double-click time of 500 ms** as the `Activate` event is raised before the enhancement can do its job.

A complete convenient solution consisting of an `IStripClickEnhancement` interface implemented by `MenuStripEx`, `StatusStripEx`, `ToolStripEx` and an auxiliary `ToolStripPanelEx` supported by a `StripClickEnhancement` component is 9 files with approx. 500 lines of code. As it neither seems feasible to copy-paste this much code here, nor seems possible to attach code files, please go to the [source code repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/y-a-terminal/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/YAT/MKY/MKY.Windows.Forms/) of the above mentioned items.

Note that this implementation further refines the **MyToolStrip solution** by using member variables rather than static ones, and by including debug code to demonstrate the operation of the enhancement.

### Unwanted side-effects of previous solution proposals

- `this.Focus()` of the **easy and clean solution** moves the cursor out of the focused control, e.g. a textbox. The following two pictures demonstrate this on moving the mouse down to the status bar:

[image: Textbox is focused]

[image: Textbox loses focus]

- The injected `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message of the **MyToolStrip solution** results in an even more tricky issue, the double-click within an `OpenFileDialog` may additionally trigger the action underneath the dialog!

[image: 1. Terminal is open]

[image: 2. File is double-clicked]

[image: 3. File gets loaded but side-effects toolbar e.g. terminal gets closed]

The red "Close Terminal" button located right underneath "b.txt" accidentally got clicked when double-clicking "b.txt"!

Looking forward seeing somebody coming up with an even more elegant implementation still covering all these aspects.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be simpler solution:

Register MainMenu component onto Toolbox bar, (in Visual Studio, use menu "Tools", then option "Choose Toolbox Items", then find "MainMenu"), and then use it on a form instead of MenuStrip.

Answer (score -1):

You can detect the click on your form even when the application doesn't have focus if you subscribe for the `MouseClick` event.

Then, when you click your form, you'll get the callback whether the form previously had focus or not.

Then you can simulate the click on the control that you want.

This isn't a terribly elegant solution, but it should work.  You do have to make sure that the click doesn't get sent to your toolbar button twice.